# Convert long data.frame to sequence in TraMineR

Tags: r, traminer, sequence-analysis

I have a data.frame in long format, that I want to convert to a `TraMineR` sequence object.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1990:2010, 3),
                 id = rep(1:3, each = 21),
                 value = sample(10, 63, replace = TRUE))
```

AFAIK, none of the formats described in the [manual](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf) support this format.

What would be an easy way to convert this data.frame to a sequence object? With `id` the individual, `year` the time and `value` the state. One can convert first to wide (see answer), but I wonder whether this format is natively supported by `TraMineR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TraMineR` indeed prefers data in wide format but also can handle data in different formats by utilizing its `seqformat` function. You either could reshape the data by explicitly calling `seqformat`(as recommended in the manual) or within the `seqdef` call. Data stored in the long format could be conceived as a special type of SPELL data in which each spell is of length 1.

```
# Option 1
seqformat(df,
          from = "SPELL", to = "STS",
          id = "id", 
          begin = "year", end = "year", 
          status = "value",
          process = FALSE, limit = 21) |> 
  seqdef()

# Option 2
seqdef(df,
       var = c("id", "year", "year", "value"), # start and end date = year
       informat = "SPELL",
       process = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to convert to wide first, and then use `seqdef`.

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = "year") |>
  seqdef(var = -1)

#  Sequence                                     
#1 9-4-7-1-2-7-2-3-1-5-5-10-6-10-7-9-5-5-9-9-5  
#2 5-2-10-9-1-4-3-6-10-10-6-4-4-10-9-7-6-9-8-9-7
#3 8-6-10-7-3-10-6-8-2-2-6-6-1-3-3-8-6-7-6-8-7
```